# Change multiple items in a list

Tags: python, list, slice

I want to change ,multiple values in a list, for example, every multiple of 2. Using slicing.
my logic is:

```
list = [0] * 10
list[::2] = 1
```

However, I get an error message:
" must assign iterable to extended slice"
Can someone explain the error and also the correct logic to preform something like this? Thanks.

Comment: The slicing you did will return a list, and you can't just set that list equal to 1.

Comment: @SuperStew no, that *does not return a list at all*. That is slice-based assignment.

Comment: Note:  `numpy` does things the "one obvious way" here.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga obviously not because it doesn't work.

Comment: @SuperStew that doesn't follow at all. the expression `my_list[<some slice>] = <something else>` **never creates an intermediate list**. Instead, it passes `<some slice>` as an argument to `my_list.__setitem__`. It is simply incorrect to state that a `list` is returned.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign to a `slice` of a `list`, you need the assignment to be a `list` of the same length as the `slice`. For your example, assign a list of 5 ones:

```
l = [0] * 10
l[::2] = [1] *5
```

It isn't obvious why in this example, but if you think about it, you were doing:

```
l[3:6] = 2
```

Obviously that doesn't make sense. You are trying to assign an `int` to a `list`, which *won't* work. `l[::2]` is just another way to slice a `list`, so you must assign a `list` to it.

In the future, don't name your lists `"list"` because doing so overrides the builtin `list()` function.

Comment: *l[::2] is just another way to slice a list, so you must assign a list to it.*  Well, not really.  When this is on the left hand of an assignment statement it's hooking into `list.__setitem__`.  That could be implemented to accept a scalar.

Comment: @wim it obviously isn't implemented that way though. We are working with the Python built ins, not some library which you could change.

Comment: It's still incorrect statement regardless.  You can for example assign the string 'hello' here.

Answer (score 2):

`my_list[::2]` has `10//2` (=5) elements, so the right part of the assignment should have `10//2` elements as well:

```
>>> my_list = [0] * 10
>>> my_list[::2] = [1]*(10//2)
>>> my_list
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Or you could use `numpy` with [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.zeros(10)
>>> a
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
>>> a[::2] = 1
>>> a
array([ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.])
```